# Order entries by date field

Tags: entries, datetime, elementcriteriamodel, ordering

I have a channel section with a handle named 'events'.

In my field layout for this section I have a field named eventsDate, which is a Date/Time field.

I also have a plain text field called 'eventsHeadline'.

What would be a good way to output the 'eventsHeadline' entries ordered by 'eventsDate'?

Comment: Is "eventsFeed" an entries field or did you mean it's a section? If it really is an entries field, what's the section handle of your sections and where do you use the datetime field "eventsDate"?

Comment: Ok. "eventsFeed" is missing altogether now, updated my answer :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Read the article about [ElementCriteriaModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel) in the official Craft docs on how to query elements in general and the [craft.entries](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries) article about the parameter available to modify the object returned.

Example code for your events list:

```twig
{# Get events from `events` section in desired sort order #}
{% set allEvents = craft.entries.section('events').order('eventsDate desc') %}

{# Loop through `allEvents` and print the list #}
{% for event in allEvents %}
    <li>{{ event.eventsHeadline }} - {{ event.eventsDate|date('F j, Y') }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: If I was wrong and "eventsFeed" is an entries field, query your events with the [`relatedTo()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/relations#the-relatedTo-param) parameter.

Comment: Yes, eventsFeed is an entries field, . Could you update your example code for the events list? Meanwhile, I'll read the articles you suggested.

Comment: I can't because you first have to provide more info.

Comment: Sorry about that. I just updated my question.